# how to log trigger intiated CRUD queries on postgresql 8.4

Tags: postgresql

in the postgresql config file there is an option

log_statement = 'mod'

which causes CRUD statements to be logged.

However this does not include the CRUD statements that are called from trigger functions, which means that following the log file is not useful to determine what changes are being made to the database data, if the 3rd part application has been making lots of changes using triggers.

Is there some other option I can use to include trigger CRUD?

alternatively, can I inspect the pg_xlog in real time using some tool?

(xlogdump and xlogviewer do not work with version 8.4, i have tried)